# twitter card gallery doesn't work

Tags: html, twitter, metadata, twitter-card

I'm trying to use the Twitter card **gallery** but doesn't work when I use the validator says

`twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found`

this is my code:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="gallery">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@hoteloposada" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@ccdiego5" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="http://www.hoteloposada.com/venezuela/tachira/id002/twitter/1.html" />
<meta name="twitter:image0" content="http://www.hoteloposada.com/venezuela/tachira/id002/1.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image1" content="http://www.hoteloposada.com/venezuela/tachira/id002/3.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image2" content="http://www.hoteloposada.com/venezuela/tachira/id002/5.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:image3" content="http://www.hoteloposada.com/venezuela/tachira/id002/6.jpg">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Hotel Taj Mahal Suite C.A. - 0276 3472849, San Cristóbal, Táchira.">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Hotel Taj Mahal Suite C.A. - 0276 3472849, Av. Rotaria Edificio Taj Mahal, Sector Los Criollitos, San Cristóbal, Táchira.">
```

this is my .html
http://www.hoteloposada.com/venezuela/tachira/id002/twitter/1.html

I don't know what exactly happened here, because I'm using the **meta twitter card gallery**

https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator

[image: twitter:card = summary_large_image tag found]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh dammit, [twitter deprecating the photo gallery and product cards](https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecating-the-photo-gallery-and-product-cards/38961) so ugly. . .